# How can I use Linq expression for full Join with multiple table with GroupBy in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, eager-loading, ef-core-3.1

I have the following 4 models. I want to Full-join and group them with LINQ in my ASP Core API Application. I want to join all my WarehouseDelivery,WarehouseDeliveryLine,WarehouseReceipt, WarehouseReceiptLine to get Input And OutPut Item Quantity of each item. please help me to write the LINQ query with best practices,
I write this query in TSQL. but I need in LINQ or LINQ method. but I can't convert this query to LINQ

```
  public class WarehouseDelivery 
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
     public string DeliveryComment { get; set; }
   //...
   //navigation
   public ICollection<WarehouseDeliveryLine> WarehouseDeliveryLines { get; set; }
   public ICollection<WarehouseReceipt> WarehouseReceipts { get; set; }
   }


    public class WarehouseDeliveryLine
    {
      public int Id{ get; set; }
      public int WarehouseDeliveryId { get; set; }
      public int? ReturnWarehouseDeliveryLineId { get; set; }
      public int ItemId { get; set; }
      public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
     //navigation    
     public WarehouseDelivery WarehouseDelivery { get; set; }
     public ICollection<WarehouseReceiptLine> WarehouseReceiptLines { get; set; }
     public WarehouseDeliveryLine ReturnBase { get; set; }
     public List<WarehouseDeliveryLine> Children { get; set; }
    }

   public class WarehouseReceipt : BaseEntity
    {
      public int Id{ get; set; }
      public int? WarehouseDeliveryId { get; set; }
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }
      public string Comment { get; set; }
      //navigation
      public ICollection<WarehouseReceiptLine> WarehouseReceiptLines { get; set; }
      public WarehouseDelivery WarehouseDelivery { get; set; }
    }

  public class WarehouseReceiptLine : BaseEntity
  {
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public int WarehouseReceiptId { get; set; }
    public int WarehouseDeliveryLineId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId{ get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Comment{ get; set; }
    //navigation
    public WarehouseReceipt WarehouseReceipt { get; set; }
    public WarehouseDeliveryLine WarehouseDeliveryLine { get; set; }
   }
```

i write this query in SQL Server, but i need to convert it to Linq , please help me,

```
      Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.Id, Warehouse.WarehouseReceipts.Id AS Expr1, Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.ItemId, Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.Comment, 
                     Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveryLines.ItemId AS Expr2, 
      Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveryLines.Quantity, Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.Quantity AS 
      Expr3
      FROM            Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveries FULL OUTER JOIN
                     Warehouse.WarehouseReceipts ON Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveries.Id = 
                        Warehouse.WarehouseReceipts.WarehouseDeliveryId AND 
                     Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveries.Id = 
                        Warehouse.WarehouseReceipts.WarehouseDeliveryId FULL OUTER JOIN
                     Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveryLines ON Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveries.Id = 
                        Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveryLines.WarehouseDeliveryId FULL OUTER JOIN
                     Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines ON Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveryLines.Id = 
                        Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.WarehouseDeliveryLineId AND 
                     Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveryLines.Id = 
                        Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.WarehouseDeliveryLineId AND 
                     Warehouse.WarehouseReceipts.Id = 
                        Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.WarehouseReceiptId
                     GROUP BY Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.Id, 
                       Warehouse.WarehouseReceipts.Id, 
                       Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.ItemId, 
                       Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.Comment, 
                       Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveryLines.ItemId, 
                       Warehouse.WarehouseDeliveryLines.Quantity, 
                       Warehouse.WarehouseReceiptLines.Quantity
```

Comment: Start with a single join, and work you're way through. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#join

Comment: `I need to convert it to Linq` why? ORMs are **not** meant for reporting queries. They're built to load *entities* and their relations from relational data as a graph of connected objects.  EF Core makes it easier to write GROUP By's but it will never be as powerful as a simple reporting query.  Assuming `Delivery` is the root, you could flatten all receipts and deliveries with `from delivery in ctx.Deliveries from dl in delivery.DeliveryLines from rl in delivery.ReceiptLines group by ..... into g select new {.....}`

Comment: Is that what you really need though? Or would it be better to create a new entity that *maps* to the results of a reporting view and groups/projects only the fields necessary?

Comment: hi Panagiotis Kanavos , please explain to me,

Comment: can you show us some sample data and expected outcome?